# How to send Python variable to bash variable?

Tags: python, system

I am trying to use Python to select a variable from a list, then speak it outloud using the bash command. Right now I have something like this

```
foo = ["a","b","c","d"]
from random import choice
x = choice(foo)
foo.remove(x)
from os import system
system('say x')
```

This says "x", what I need is for it to say the value of the `x` variable.

Comment: Nice, I dind't knew that Mac OS X has `say` :)

Comment: For the curious, [os.putenv](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.putenv) is how to export variables to the environment and subprocesses

Comment: Have you tried `system('say ' + str(x))` ?

Comment: @mgilson You are spot on, edited the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you can use `os.system`, but better might be `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['say',x])
```

Answer (score 2):

you are passing  astring you can use value of x like

`sytem('say {0}'.format(x))`

When passing strings you can use string formatting. As you realized you need to get the value of x in the string not the variable x
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: Note that this is the old style of string formatting, and in new software, ``str.format()`` is the recommended method - e.g: ``system('say {0}'.format(x))``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
system('say {}'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

use string formatting:

```
In [9]: x="ls -ld"

In [10]: os.system("{0}".format(x))
drwxr-xr-x 41 monty monty 4096 2012-10-10 22:46 .
Out[10]: 0
```

Comment: `os.system` is inflexible and can be error-prone and insecure. The `subprocess` module provides much better functionality for this.

Comment: `"{0}".format("value")` is just an incredibly complex way to say `"value"`.